# asp.net ListView sort by column

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, sorting

I have a list view binded to a data source.
How can I enable sorting by column?

So when clicking the column title once it sorts by ascending, click it again it sorts by descending.

Is there anything in the wizard that can be setup or it all needs to be done programatically?

Comment: Have you seen this **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listview.sorting.aspx**

Comment: Generally this is either done in the code-behind or in the database. Can you provide which framework version you are using? That will help provide a best solution, especially if you can use LINQ.

Comment: Google found this article, first in the list.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319401

Complete source available.

Comment: How can I fix the above to work for data bound sources? I keep getting The data source 'reportObjectDataSource' does not support sorting with IEnumerable data. Automatic sorting is only supported with DataView, DataTable, and DataSet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the DataSource you are using. If the Data Source allows sorting, it can be set up in the way described here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa88ktts.aspx . Otherwise you have to handle sorting yourself programatically. Usually that is even easier than the automatical approach.

Comment: I am getting an ObjectDataSource does not allow sorting of  IEnumerable. Is there a way to configure the data source to allow it?

Comment: Try this - http://www.vinull.com/Post/2007/04/17/aspnet-sorting-a-gridview-with-custom-o.aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you are using a data source control then sorting can be implemented in the ListView control without having to write a single line of code - it is all handled automatically by the ListView and its data source control. Of course, in more advanced scenarios we may need to manually sort the data or programmatically.

In the following example, ListView will be sorted by ProductName and UnitPrice. simply add two LinkButtons in the ListView's LayoutTemplate with appropriate CommandName and CommandArgument property values.

```
    <asp:ListView ID="ProductList" runat="server" DataSourceID="ProductDataSource">
   <LayoutTemplate>
      <h3>Product Listing</h3>
       <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="SortByName" CommandName="Sort"
                     CommandArgument="ProductName">Sort by Name</asp:LinkButton>
      | <asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="SortByPrice" CommandName="Sort"
                     CommandArgument="UnitPrice">Sort by Price</asp:LinkButton>

      <blockquote>
         <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
      </blockquote>
   </LayoutTemplate>

   ...
</asp:ListView>
```

If a user clicks the "Sort by Price" link twice in a row, the first time the products will be sorted in ascending order (from cheapest to most expensive), but the second time the sort order will reverse.

Comment: Please insert the important parts from the link in your answer.